# Is there any way i can make one command apply for all buttons

Tags: c#, button, audio

i am making a tool, and i figured out how to do a sound effect for a button. Is there any way that i can make one command apply for all buttons instead of having to put the definition i made for the sound effect before each buttons coding. i know putting the command before the coding on each button will work, but is there a way to do this? thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking, but it is possible to use the same handler for more than one control.

Comment: please post your code showing how you're triggering the sound effect for a button click, and the html for some of your buttons.

Comment: SoundPlayer My_BetterJukeBox = new SoundPlayer(Resource1.play);

Comment: to call it i just do this:

Comment: My_BetterJukeBox.Play();

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about WinForms or WebForms, you can do something like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Button b in Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        b.Click += MakeSoundEffect;
    }
}

private void MakeSoundEffect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

This will take all buttons on your form and, when clicked, it will execute `MakeSoundEffect`. You can use the `sender` object to determine which button, specifically, was pushed.

If your `MakeSoundEffect()` method is simple enough, you might want to use a lambda to create a closure, like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Button b in Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        b.Click += (btnSender, btnEvent) =>
        {
            // Do Something
        };
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you don't want all buttons, but maybe just buttons whose names start with `btnSoundEffect`, you can change the `foreach` loop to something like this:

```
foreach (Button b in Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(z => z.Name.StartsWith("btnSoundEffect")))
```

Probably the better way, if you need just specific buttons is to create a group on your form and put all the buttons in that group, then just change your `for` loop to this:

```
foreach (Button b in grpButtons.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: @puregamer62 - What was wrong, specifically? I tried it on my end and it worked just fine.